# Mulitple Search Forms With Search Options

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am using this [nice old script](http://www.mediacollege.com/internet/javascript/form/multi-search-radio.html) to search 2 site locations and it is working great until I place the search form in multiple places on the same HTML page.  Having multiple placements of this form cancels everything out.

The goal is to be able to have this search form in 3-4 places on the same HTML page.

HTML FORM

```
     <form name="searchform" class="top-search-bar-multiple" role="search" onsubmit="return dosearch();">
<input type="text" name="searchterms" placeholder="Search our products" />
<button type="submit" name="SearchSubmit" class="search-bar--submit icon-fallback-text">
  <span class="icon icon-search" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span class="fallback-text">search</span>
</button>
<input name="sengines" type="radio" value="http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=" checked/> <small>query 1</small> &nbsp;
<input name="sengines" type="radio" value="http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=" /> <small>query 2</small>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
    // <![CDATA[
function dosearch() {
  var sf=document.searchform;
  for (i=sf.sengines.length-1; i > -1; i--) {
    if (sf.sengines[i].checked) {
      var submitto = sf.sengines[i].value + escape(sf.searchterms.value);
    }
  }
  window.location.href = submitto;
  return false;
}
// ]]>
```

Comment: I would assume if you are naming the search form the same thing every time, then the script doesn't know which `document.searchform` to grab so the search result ends up being empty. Does the first search form always work no matter how many come afterwards? Or do all of them break when there is more than one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As already mentioned, it simply doesn't know which form element to search.

Besides the fact, that this code could need some refactoring - if all you want is just a fast and simple solution, simply forward the form as parameter in the `onsubmit="return dosearch(currentForm)"` and use if afterwards to search only the given form. Like this:

http://codepen.io/MattDiMu/pen/PzWYrK

Comment: THANKS - So it would not be possible for all forms to share that javascript?  So I would need separate javascript with each form?

Comment: @Jay No, it's enough to have the JavaScript only once as it works now parameterized receiving the clicked form as argument. If this answer helps, feel free to mark it as answer :)